# How can I use directory paths as names for HDF5 groups?

Tags: python, hdf5

I am trying to create a function, which:
  opens a directory
  reads all files
  performs some calculation
  writes the result into an HDF5 file

The Problem:
For every directory, I would like to create an HDF5 group. However,

```
with h5py.File(/home/usr/example/myFile.h5) as h5:
    dir_i_am currently_reading = '/home/usr/files/'
    group = h5.create_group(dir_i_am currently_reading)
```

Does not work as intended. I would like the group name to be the dir_path. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: The problem is the directory name separator (`/`) is also used as the HDF5 group name separator. So your directory path: `/home/usr/files/` looks like a group with subgroups, like this in h5py nomenclature: `h5['home']['usr']['files']`. Is that what you want? If not, you will have to replace the `/` with another character (say `_`) to create as `h5.create_group('_home_usr_files')`.

Answer (score 0):

In case [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) is an option for you, your question can be solved as follows in Python:

```python
import HDFql

dir_i_am_currently_reading = "/home/usr/files"

HDFql.execute("CREATE GROUP /home/usr/example/myFile.h5 %s" % dir_i_am_currently_reading)
```

Additional examples on how to create groups using HDFql can be found in the [quick start guide](http://www.hdfql.com/quickstart) and [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf).